# Where's my Azure Cache in the new portal?

Tags: caching, azure

In the old silverlight portal, azure cache was under the service bus category along with ACS. In the new HTML5 portal, I can't find my cache anywhere. Under ServiceBus, it says I have zero, and only shows a link to create a new service bus namespace. Should I contact support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the [previous portal](https://windows.azure.com/) for managing the **Azure Cache**. Since the new portal is still in beta - not all features have been ported yet. MSDN still links to the previous portal for [provisioning the Azure Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg618004.aspx).

**Update by question asker**: As seen in the comments, it looks like my browser may have been hanging onto a DNS redirect from windows.azure.com to manage.windowsazure.com. I was able to successfully get back to the silverlight portal using both the [provisioning the Azure Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg618004.aspx) link and by using @BrentDaCodeMonkey's suggestion.

Comment: That is the URL I am using. It used to take me to the SL portal. Since about a week or 2 ago, it has started taking me to the HTML5 portal, which no longer says "preview". There are also no longer any links back to the SL portal from the HTML5 one as far as I can tell.

Comment: click on your name in the new portal and you'll get a drop down menu that contains the link to go to the old portal. :)

Comment: It looks like the [portal went into **Release Mode** 10/30/12 - despite lacking certain provisioning features](http://jeremiedevillard.wordpress.com/2012/06/08/how-to-access-new-azure-management-portal/). I'm sure they'll be coming soon. Thanks @BrentDaCodeMonkey for the helpful guidance!